# Creating duplicates with a different ID for test in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, self-join

I have a table with 1000 unique records with one of the field as ID. For testing purpose, my requirement is that To update the last 200 records ID value to the first 200 records ID in the same table. Sequence isn't mandatory.

Appreciate help on this.

Comment: I think this update can not be done using join.

Comment: I assume you want to test what happens if you do have duplicates? If so, you can simply insert top 200 from the same table.

Comment: Gosh your professor needs to come up with something resembling real world scenarios. This is so strange it can't be anything other than homework.

Comment: The problem has a larger view than what you actually see. Just brought into plain words. Thnx for the response :) Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Typically I charge for doing other ppls homework, don't forget to cite your source ;)

```
declare @example as table (
    exampleid int identity(1,1) not null
,   color nvarchar(255) not null
);

insert into @example (color)
select 'black' union all
select 'green' union all
select 'purple' union all
select 'indigo' union all
select 'yellow' union all
select 'pink';

select *
  from @example; 

declare @max int = (select max(exampleId) from @example);
declare @min int = @max - 2

;with cte as (
    select top 2 color
      from @example
            )

update @example 
   set color = a.color
  from cte a
 where exampleid <= @max and exampleid > @min;

 select *
   from @example
```

Answer (score 0):

This script should solve the issue and will cover scenarios even if the id column is not sequential.I have included the comments to help you understand the joins and the flow of the script.

```
    declare  @test  table
    (
     ID int  not null,
     Txt char(1)
    )

    declare @counter int = 1

    /*******This variable is the top n or bottom n records in question it is 200 , 
            for test purpose setting it to 20
     ************/ 
    declare @delta int = 20 

    while(@counter <= 50)
    begin 
     Insert into @test values(@counter * 5,CHAR(@counter+65))
     set @counter = @counter + 1
    end

    /************Tag the records with a row id as we do not know if ID's are sequential or random ************/
    Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) rownum,*  into #tmp from @test


    /************Logic to update the data ************/
    /*Here we first do a self join on the tmp table  with first 20 to last 20 
      then create another join to the test table based on the ID of the first 20
    */
    update t
    set t.ID = tid.lastID
    --Select t.ID , tid.lastID
    from @test t inner join 
    (
    Select f20.rownum as first20 ,l20.rownum as last20,f20.ID as firstID, l20.ID lastID 
        from #tmp f20 
        inner join #tmp l20 on (f20.rownum + @delta) = l20.rownum  
    )tid on tid.firstID = t.ID and tid.first20 < = @delta


    Select * from @test

    drop table #tmp
```